# How to get the variable's value from a plguin or send the value out from the plugin?

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I get the variable's value from a plguin or send the value out from the plugin?

For instance this is my plugin which retrieves user information via ajax and it stores the user information in the variable,

```
(function($){

   $.fn.extend({ 

        get_authentication: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                file:           'authentication_json.php',
                location:       'cms/'
            }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            var o = options;
            var object = $(this); // now the object is the selected element such as #popup

            $.get(http_root + rp_cms+ o.file, function(data){

                if(data) var user_id = data.user_id;

                // Redirect if the date returns as 'expired'.
                if(data && data.error == 'expired') window.location = http_root + o.location;
                //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

            },"json");
        }
    });

 })(jQuery);
```

I call this plugin when I click on a certain links,

```
$('.get-user').click(function(){

   $.fn.get_authentication();
   alert(user_id);
});
```

I get an error like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your plugin don't use object as a var name. object is a javascript reserved name http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a callback to your plugin. Here's an example + modified code

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        get_authentication: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                file: 'authentication_json.php',
                location: 'cms/',
                callback: function(user_id) {}
            }
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            var o = options;
            var object = $(this); // now the object is the selected element such as #popup
            $.get(http_root + rp_cms + o.file, function(data) {
                if (data)
                    options.callback(data.user_id);

                // Redirect if the date returns as 'expired'.
                if (data && data.error == 'expired') window.location = http_root + o.location;
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            }, "json");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $.fn.get_authentication({
        callback: function(user_id) {
            alert(user_id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: THanks so much for this answer, Manuel. `callback` is something new I just learned from you today for writing a plugin. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As Manuel said use a callback.

Comment: the `$.get` triggers a event when the request is completed. at the time that happens the function is already finished and won't return anything